# how to chain the calls

Tags: couchbase, spring-webflux, reactor

My question must be so basic but any help is appreciated

I have a object like below

```
{
    "type":"type_value",
    "fruits" :[{"amt": 5},{"amt": 10}],
    "shops" : [{"location": "X"},{"location": "Y"}]
}
```

I am using Spring WebFlux and couchbase.
Couchbase supports collections and I am looking to store above object in 3 collections. the array of fruits/shops can contain any number of elements.

Couchbase has 'insert' function which returns Mono on one insertion.
e.g.

Step 1:

```
Mono<TransactionGetResult> insertResult = ctx.insert(reactiveCollectio, id, objectToPersist)
```

I can only insert next element on 'insertResult' object. like below
Step 2:

```
 Mono<TransactionGetResult> insertResult = insertResult.then(ctx.insert(reactiveCollectio, id, objectToPersist));
```

again now if I want to insert next element I have to follow same as step 2 and keep doing until I am done then only I can commit the transaction.

using reactor api's how can I iterate and and within same how to use previous result ( `Mono<TransactionGetResult> insertResult` ) to perform my insertion?

Comment: Use `ctx.insert(...).map(result -> ...)`

Comment: can you explain with a sample code snippet, how I will get next element in my stream and how this will work when I have unknown number of elements in list?

Comment: Which list are you talking? Your return is an object wrapped in a Mono: `Mono<TransactionGetResult> `

Comment: I have list of fruits which I am trying to insert, he list can contain any number of elements.

I can only insert second element after I get result of Mono<TransactionGetResult>

Comment: Is the list of fruits `reactiveCollectio`? If so, you have to iterate `reactiveCollectio` outside of the `ctx.insert(` with a `foreach`

Comment: ReactiveCollection is an instance pointing to couchbase collection ( which is equivalent to table in relational database). fruits is an array which I want to persist but the only way is I need to take first entry then call insert on it, take the response from last insert and call insert on next element.

In a usual for loop it can be written as follows

Comment: ````
Mono<TransactionGetResult> transactionResult = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < fruitsList.size(); i++) {
      Fruit fruit1 = fruitsList.get(i);
      String fruitId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
      System.out.println("Fruit Id: " + fruitId);
      fruit1.setIdIfNotPresent(fruitId);
      if (transactionResult == null) {
        transactionResult = ctx.insert(collection, fruit1.getId(), fruit1);
      } else {
        transactionResult = transactionResult.then(ctx.insert(collection, fruit1.getId(), fruit1));
      }
    }
````

Comment: @Toerktumlare : are you part of stack overflow team?

Comment: Just to clarify I am not here to buy any code either if people are selling code. Thanks for your inputs anyway.

Comment: `can you explain with a sample code snippet, how I will get next element in my stream and how this will work when I have unknown number of elements in list` please post what you have tried first, and we will help you work through your problems.

Comment: @Satya have you looked through the examples on the docs (https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/current/howtos/distributed-acid-transactions-from-the-sdk.html)?  Generally with Reactive Mono you will use .flatMap() or .then() to combine ops.  E.g. `return ctx.insert(...).flatMap(ignored -> ctx.insert(...)).flatMap(ignored -> ctx.insert(...))`.  Or `return ctx.insert(...).then(ctx.insert(...)).then(ctx.insert(...))`